# How to retrieve a javascript object from variable

Tags: javascript

I have several js objects, obj1{}, obj2{}...

My code is taking values from a js obj{}

This obj has to change when user click at on different elements of document which have a dataset with the name of corresponding object.

Example:

```
<button data-itemname="obj1>item 1</button>
<button data-itemname="obj2>item 2</button>
```

Following user click, I have obj1, obj2 as string variable.

How to retrieve the object obj1{} from this string obj1

I tried several syntax, but not working.

Actually, all values coming from an object obj{}. If can change obj{} to obj1{}, obj2{}... that would be the best.

I can also restructure my code. Or put everything in 1 obj: obj = { obj1:{} , obj2{}, ...}
thanks

Comment: Do not use "several variables". Use an object or `Map` to store those objects by name.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not that JavaScript expert and what u want to do, i know from php with {$varname} in JS i was found a different solution which does what u want for me since some years. (Its my way in React)

JS is kind of strange in object and array handling, u can access objects like a array, this is the magic, i access the all object which contents everything like a array and get so the wanted path with the object you want. This "hello" can be replaced by everything also other objects.

The Onclick handler submits the button to the function so i can access the data attribute.

U also should take a look if the object path u want exists in the all object.

Maybe there are better ways.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <button data-itemname="obj1">item 1</button>
    <button data-itemname="obj2">item 2</button>

    <script>
      let all = { obj1: "hello 1", obj2: "hello 2" };

      function getObj(sel) {
        return all[sel.dataset.itemname];
      }

      (function () {
        var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
        for (i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
          buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
            console.log(getObj(this));
          });
        }
      })();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add some additional explanation about what you changed in the code, how that solves the problem, and why it's the best solution.

Comment: @Bergi can you please explain me why using sel.dataset and not using getAttribute?

Comment: [Same thing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) but simpler and shorter, imo. If you don't like the edit, please feel free to [roll it back](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74591752/revisions) - it's your answer.

Comment: @Bergi no problem, only interested because i did your way in the past and on ES2016 I have seen my old solution often.

Answer (score 1):

This little variation might do it:

```js
var obj1={a:123,b:456},obj2={c:789,d:10123};
const obj={obj1,obj2};

document.body.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
 if(e.target.tagName=="BUTTON")
  console.log(obj[e.target.dataset["itemname"]]);
});
```

```html
<button data-itemname="obj1">item 1</button>
<button data-itemname="obj2">item 2</button>
```

Global variables can be accessed through the `window` object.

Following @Bergi's suggestion I modified my snippet to now work with the global `obj` object.

Comment: Can, but shouldn't, be accessed. Especially when the OP already offers "*I can also restructure my code. Or put everything in 1 obj: `obj = { obj1:{} , obj2{}, ...}`*"

Comment: Yes, that would be a slightly better solution, of course.

Comment: this version works great. Very nice trick to declare the const obj = {obj1, obj2} ! That makes all the difference when assigning variable after the clicked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

Changes made to access the data object property if required

---

You can make use of the event object if you are using a event handler like onclick or get a reference to the element and access the dataset directly on it. On events object there is
`event.target.dataset` object which will contain the itemname property.

```js
const item1 = document.querySelector("#btn1");
const item2 = document.querySelector("#btn2");

const data = {
  object1: {
    a: 1,
    b: 2
  },
  object2: {
    a: 3,
    b: 4
  },
}

const handleBtnClick = (e) => {
  const targetElemName = e.target.dataset["itemname"];
  console.log(`access the ${targetElemName} val:`, data[targetElemName]);
};

item1.addEventListener('click', handleBtnClick);
item2.addEventListener('click', handleBtnClick);
```

```html
<button id="btn1" data-itemname="object1">item 1</button>
<button id="btn2" data-itemname="object2">item 2</button>
```

Comment: that's what I'm doing, my problem is to convert the result of that "object1" which is a string variable to the object which has the name object1{}

Comment: @connexo when i understand him correct he want access the variable with the same name like the name he gave over dataset.

Comment: @pierfarrugia You can't directly access a variable from a string. What you can do is create a object and inside those you can then access. I have modified my example for the changes